# Django getting error 403

Tags: python, django

I'm working on multi file upload. Everything works fine but there is one problem. Files are moving to the directory which i want but when i try to display them i get this error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /media/taka-se/image026.jpg on this server.
```

Here is views.py:

```
def post(self, request):
        form = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            gallery = cd['gallery']
            for image in cd['image']:
                Photo.objects.create(gallery=gallery, image=image)
            return redirect(reverse('account:gallery', kwargs={'postid': gallery.pk}))
```

Here is forms.py:

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = MultiImageField(
        min_num=1,
        max_num=25,
        max_file_size=429916160,
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('gallery',)
```

Comment: What user is the application running as?  What is the ownership of the `/media` directory?

Comment: Path to media is /home/login/project/media

Comment: I didn’t ask the path, I asked about ownership and permissions.  The error indicates you don’t have permissions, which leads me to try and diagnose by evaluating what the permissions are.